# Using groovy.transform.Field to define another Field

Tags: groovy, field

I am writing a Groovy script, where I need to use some of my fields inside closures. Below is a very simplified example to demonstrate my problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

import groovy.transform.Field

@Field def first = 'one'
assert first == 'one'
```

So far so good. In my real-world case, this will hold a String representing a server name. I then modify this "default" value from command-line options - using CliBuilder() - maybe something like:

```
first = 'two'
assert first == 'two'
```

This still works. I now need to create a new field, from the one above:

```
@Field def second = first
assert second == 'two'
```

In my real-world case, this will be an HTTPBuilder() that I will be making REST calls with.

This fails:

```
Assertion failed: 

assert second == 'two'
       |      |
       'one'  false
```

Is there a way to get this to work?

A failed attempt to somehow work around this. Using an intermediary, something like:

```
def intermediary = first
assert intermediary == 'two'
@Field def second = intermediary
```

Fails with:

```
Caught: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at something.main(something)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: intermediary for class: something
    at something.<init>(something)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: could you explain why do you need the mix of fields(class members) and local script variables?

Comment: @daggett Sorry, I should have been more clear. Using the "intermediary" was just something I thought of to get this to work; it is irrelevant to my task. "This" being "@Field def second = first". I clarified my OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the annotation `@Field` declares member of the script class and any other script commands will go to `script.run()` method

for example the script

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field def first = 'one'
first = 'two'
@Field def second = first
assert second == 'two' // <<<---- fails because second=='one'
```

will be transformed approximately to this class during script compilation:

```
class scriptXXXX{
    Object first
    Object second
    
    scriptXXXX(){ // constructor
        first = 'one'
        second = first
    }

    void run(){ // script body
        first = 'two'
        assert second == 'two' : null    
    }
}
```

You could see this in `groovyconsole` by pressing `Ctrl+T`

[image]

---

as a variant you could separate field declaration and initialization:

```
@Field def first = 'one'
@Field def second
first = 'two'
second = first
assert second == 'two'
```

Comment: maybe fix typo "@Filed" => "@Field" :)